# Filter dict in python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to get only certain values from a given dict. My dict looks like this:

```
my_dict = {
    "Value1": "2000",
    "Value2": "3000",
    "Value3": "4000"
}

for (key,value) in my_dict:
    if (int(value) > 2000):
        print(value)
```

How can I return only the corresponding (key, value) pairs for values that are above 2000? Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.items()` like this:

```
my_dict = {
    "Value1": "2000",
    "Value2": "3000",
    "Value3": "4000"
}

for (key,value) in my_dict.items():
    if (int(value) > 2000):
        print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks, .items() made it simple. I see the method now on the w3schools.

Answer (score 4):

If the dictionary is not too big, it may be cheaper to reconstruct it without the unwanted values with a dictionary comprehension. *"This is the [Python] way."*

```
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if int(v) > 2000}
#{'Value2': '3000', 'Value3': '4000'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
my_dict = {
    "Value1": "2000",
    "Value2": "3000",
    "Value3": "4000"
}

for key in my_dict:
    if not int(my_dict[key]) > 2000:
       my_dict.pop(key,None)

print(my_dict)
```

The idea is to remove the keys that do not met the condition

Comment: @ggorlen - Thanks for the catch , updated the answere

Comment: All right. I'd also use `<=` instead of `not ... >`. A dict comp is probably cleanest but does use more memory, `my_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if int(v) > 2000}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dict = {
    "Value1": "2000",
    "Value2": "3000",
    "Value3": "4000"
}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if int(value) > 2000:
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: Yes, .items() did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it by iterating *only over keys* — when you know the dictionary' key, *you know the value, too:*

```
my_dict = {
    "Value1": "2000",
    "Value2": "3000",
    "Value3": "4000"
}

for key in my_dict:
    value = my_dict[key]
    if int(value) > 2000:
        print(key, value)
```